# How to make flashing python text changes word to next in list each flash

Tags: python, tkinter

how do I get the label in show_word to update to the next item in the list words?
I've been at this for a while now and no progress :/ thanks for your help in advance.

I need to essentially get the label which would ideally be the items in the list to be updated per label flash with the next item in the list etc.

The image below is what the screen looks like

[image: Image of the screen that word flashes (for now is dummy text)]

this are the modules have chosen as i didnt want to crowd the code more than i already had.

[image]

```
def retrieve():

    output_string = StringIO()
    with open('lorem-ipsum.pdf', 'rb') as in_file:

        parser = PDFParser(in_file)
        doc = PDFDocument(parser)
        rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
        device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

        for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):

            interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = (output_string.getvalue())
    words = text.split()


def quit(*args):

    root.destroy()


def show_word():

    #flashing text where each flash the word changes to the next in the list in retrieve
    lbl.config(text = "changing word", foreground=next(color))
    
    root.after(100, show_word)
    

  


# Use tkinter lib 
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root.configure(background='gray9')
root.bind("x", quit)
root.bind('<Escape>', quit)

fnt = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=120, weight='bold')
lbl = ttk.Label(root, font=fnt, foreground="green2", background="gray9")
lbl.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=tk.CENTER)

show_word() 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It looks like you already are changing the color on each iteration. Changing the word is done in exactly the same way. Have you tried it?

Comment: @BryanOakley I realized about 5 minutes after posting, its always the way :)

Answer (score 0):

I just used the cycle function when setting `words = text.split`
to become `words = cycle(text.split)`.